# Using cmake on Juno

Tags: vala, release-juno, cmake

I know elementary OS [would like to move from cmake to meson](https://medium.com/elementaryos/all-aboard-the-meson-future-hype-train-2b6c478b6b9e), but cmake should still work:

> While CMake will continue to work, our official documentation and code examples will all be written around Meson, so it’s best to keep up.

I was trying to compile [snaptastic](https://github.com/bartzaalberg/snaptastic) on Juno. I installed `cmake` and `elementary-sdk` but I'm still getting the following error:

```
$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../
[sudo] password for peteruithoven:       
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindVala.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Vala", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Vala" with any of
  the following names:

    ValaConfig.cmake
    vala-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Vala" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Vala_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Vala"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Is there anything else I should install? I feel like I'm missing something like the following package, but I'm not sure how to install it.
https://github.com/rilian-la-te/cmake-vala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still on Loki, but it seems like the required `FindVala.cmake` file would come from `cmake-elementary`:

```
$ dpkg-query -L cmake-elementary
...
/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindVala.cmake
...
```

which is recommended by `elementary-sdk`.

Comment: Thanks! a "sudo apt install cmake-elementary" indeed did the trick.